# Console log not showing simple $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console.log

My console is not showing a simple log from below angular code.

I am getting a 304 Not Modified error in Firefox.

My HTML has the myApp and mainController defined and used.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Name';
    console.log($scope.name);

});
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Edit - here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Learn and Understand AngularJS</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            html, body, input, select, textarea
            {
                font-size: 1.05em;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-controller="mainController">

                <h1>Hello world!</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is file loading ..? do alert helo world .. you add ng-app in HTML, first check by simple alert in the controller.

Comment: where are you looking for your console.log.. in the console in the dev tools ?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well

Comment: Is that inside an internal `<script>` tag on the document, or are you loading in from some other source?

Comment: Just added HTML. ng-app is defined in html tag.

Comment: Adding a simple alert - alert($scope.name); - does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Has your `console.log` statement always been in your code? Or have you just added it?

If it's the former, then I'm not sure what's happening. Sorry.

If it's the latter, then it sounds like Firefox is loading a cached version of your file that doesn't include your `console.log` statement. In fact a response with a HTTP status code of 304 Not Modified isn't an error. It is the server telling the browser that the requested resource hasn't changed, so you can load your *cached* copy.

Try clearing Firefox's cache, or reloading using `Ctrl + shift + R` or `Cmd + shift + R` to override the files in the cache.

Comment: The console.log has always been there. The Ctrl + shift + R didn't seem to do anything.